# How to generate Huffman prefix code?

Tags: c++, huffman-code, prefix-tree

I'm working on a c++ program and my group and I cannot figure out the logic on how to generate the prefix code using an inOrder traversal.  We have the PrefixCode Tree built and we want to generate the codes from that.

Since we are having issues with the logic I don't know if I need to provide any code.  If you need any let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code. It almost always helps, and without it the question is on a one-way trip to Holdsville

Comment: I am not sure of understanding what means "using inorder traversal". Perhaps what do you want is the list in order of pairs <symbol, prefix-code>. Is it that? Maybe if you better explain. And yes. put some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I am not sure of understanding. Buy I will try ...

First, I assume that you have already built correctly the tree.

Second, each leaf contains a symbol to be be encoded. The code of each symbol is defined by the path from the root to the leaf. Initially, when you are at the root, the code is empty. If you go to the left, then you concatenate a `0` to the code. Symmetrically, if you go to the right, then you concatenate `1`.

Third, I assume that you want the list of pairs `<symbol, code>`. `symbol` is a character and `code` is a string containing the prefix code. The result is the list of all the symbols represented by the tree along with their codes.

Now, an algorithm for producing that list would use a stack for storing the prefix from the root to the current node. Each time when you arrive to a leaf, then the code is into the stack, but inversed. Such algorithm could be as follows:

```
void codes(Node * root, stack<char> & s)
{
  if (is_leaf(root))
    {
      auto symbol = // symbol stored in the node
      string code = // the reversed stack content; that is the code of current leaf
      cout << symbol << " = " << code << endl;
    }

  s.push('0');
  codes(LLINK(root), s);
  s.pop();

  s.push('1');
  codes(RLINK(root), s);
  s.pop();
}
```

I propose a stack because is the "natural" data structure for storing the partial path from the root to a node. However, maybe it would be better a `vector<char>`. In this case you should replace `push()` by `push_back()` and `pop()` by `pop_back()`. But the advantage would be that you can build the code with a reverse iterator.

Also, instead of instruction `cout ...`, you could use a list or a vector and insert in it the pair. After, if you wish, you could sort it. Alternatively, you could use a "naturally sorted" data structure such a binary search tree and you avoid to sort. All this of course if you interest is to produce a sorted by symbol output.

I hope it has been helpful

Comment: We didn't directly implement this but it really helped us understand Huffman's!  Thank you so much!!!